# Как убрать автофокус у radio button?

Tags: css3, css

Как убрать автофокус у radio button в CSS?

Comment: так по умолчания autofocus он вроде же не установлен.
Покажите код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду, что оно выбрано изначально, то все просто.

Так будет чекнут radio:

```
<input type="radio" checked>
```

А так нет:

```
<input type="radio">
```

Погуглите на тему атрибута checked, если я правильно понял вопрос

**Update 1.** В таком случае вот ваше лекарство:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду не checked, а фокус, знаете как например при наведении или клику по ссылке вокруг образуется рамка?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk Обновил)